# 1995 VW Eurovan 5 cylinder not shifting into lower gears

Tags: vw, transmission, campervan, euro-van

My 1995 5 cylinder Eurovan has the engine light coming on and I don't think the transmission is switching gears properly, it starts out of the gate properly and switches gears a couple of times but around 30 miles an hour it doesn't jump into the next gear. A little history prior to this happening:

One of the oil pressure switches was leaking oil so I decided to replace both of them, in the process I wanted to remove the connection in the picture from the bracket it was in to give me room to the upper pressure switch and the male connection side pretty much disintegrated when I removed the connection. I was able to remove the remnants of the connection housing and insert the 3 wire connectors into the female side and it appears to be pretty solid.

I'm not really sure where these wires go yet and thought I would throw it up the board to see if someone can let me know if this is the culprit of my new problem.

My second question is if I purchase the OBD I to OBD II adapter will I be able to read the code for the engine light? I read somewhere that VW had specific software for reading the OBD I and hooking up the OBD II with the adapter will be a waste of time.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.
[image]

Comment: If those wires are in the wrong places then you may not have the change signal at the correct point. Make sure the wires are in the correct places.

Answer (score 1):

You were right Solar Mike, one side of the harness had a black, yellow and White wire and the other side had a black, yellow and a grounding wire. I at first hooked up the black to black, yellow to yellow and the white to the grounding wire. I went back and reversed the black and white so now the black is connected to the grounding wire and the white is connected to the black  wire and it is back working the way it should.

Comment: Have a good day then!